# How do I copy a NSTableView data using NSPasteBoard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to copy NSTableView data using pasteboard and want to paste it as a table in Microsoft Word. How should I do this?

I have tried copying TableView Data source as string but not able to copy the TableView itself.

```
    NSPasteboard *pasteboard=[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];


    //_fillvalue,_levelfill(Mutable array) are the data source for my tableview with 2 column


    [pasteboard clearContents];
    int i=0;
    NSMutableArray *tval=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSInteger row=[_tableView numberOfRows]; 

    for(i=0;i<(int)row;i++){

        NSString *s1=[_levelfill objectAtIndex:i]; //levelfill is datasource array

        NSLog(@"s1 value is  %@",s1);
        NSString *s2=[_fillvalue objectAtIndex:i];
        s1=[s1 stringByAppendingString:@"  "];
        s1=[s1 stringByAppendingString:s2];
        [tval addObject:s1];

    }
    [pasteboard writeObjects:tval];
```

I expect the output to be copied from tableview rather than datasource of tableview. Also is there a way to copy as a table itself which can be pasted as table directly in Microsoft word.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard clearContents];

NSMutableArray *tval = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//This is the equivalent of your for
[_levelfill enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"_levelfill value is %@", object);
    NSString *s2 = [_fillvalue objectAtIndex:idx];
    NSString *s1 = object;
    s1 = [s1 stringByAppendingString:@"  "];
    s1 = [s1 stringByAppendingString:s2];
    // Create the string representing the row and add it to the array
    [tval addObject:s1];
}];

// Set the string in the pasteboard
[pasteboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSPasteboardTypeString] owner:nil];
[pasteboard setString:[tval componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"] forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
```